# QEMU Raspbian on OSX - no network?

Tags: networking, macos, qemu

I've managed to get QEMU Raspbian running on OS X but I can't figure out how to get networking to work. I've seen details if configuring TAP network interface but this was on an Ubuntu host. Is there something equivalent on OS X? Has anyone managed to figure out Raspbian networking from a QEMU instance on Mac? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

If you don't set the `-net` parameter (or set it to `-net nic -net user`) the guest machine will get the user mode network which supports TCP and UDP (not ICMP so no ping). This should be enough for some basic usage.